# Could existing SE sites help inspire what we might ask here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I keep struggling (and trying) to better understand what kind of questions would be a good fit (on topic, scope, etc) for DevOps.SE (and I seem to notice from existing questions and comments from others that I'm not the only one). In my case, I learn most from ... mistakes, and examples. So I've been doing (some) research in another SE site that I'm pretty familiar with (= [Drupal.SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)), and where so now and then DevOps related topics show up also, and which also has DevOps related tags.

On [Drupal.SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) for example, there are plenty of questions that smell like DevOps related; quiet a few of them have 0 answers, while there are also questions that are simply closed. These might help inspire what types of questions folks are interested in for *this* site!

Below is a partial list of questions (which I created from just searching tag-names on Drupal.SE):

1. [deployment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdeployment%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdeployment%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/218746/39516).
2. [version-control](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bversion-control%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bversion-control%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2820/39516).
3. [configuration-management](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration-management) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bconfiguration-management%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bconfiguration-management%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/226805/39516).
4. [jenkins](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenkins) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/8474/39516).
5. [testing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btesting%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btesting%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/231889/39516).
6. [phing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phing) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphing%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphing%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/22212/39516).
7. [staging](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/staging) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstaging%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstaging%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/216443/39516).
8. [amazon-s3](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bamazon-s3%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bamazon-ec2%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/134353/39516).
9. [amazon-ec2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bamazon-ec2%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bamazon-s3%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/49/39516).
10. [aws](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) (with [0 answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baws%5D%20answers%3A0) and/or [closed questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baws%5D%20closed%3A1)), such as [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162188/d7-amazons3-composer-manager-and-awssdk-libraries-understanding).

To better understand what kind of Drupal-related questions could be  **on-topic** for DevOps.SE, I wonder if we can create a 10-bullet list related to these same tag-names I used here (+ same order!), and thereby indicating for each item:

- Do you think the sample question I mentioned (via the "this question"-link each time) would be on-topic or off-topic?
- Can you name (via a similar linked question on Drupal.SE) another question that you'd consider as on-topic for DevOps.SE (where appropriate with some comment why you say so)?

Should you stumble upon other DevOps related tags on Drupal.SE, please include them in your answer also.

**Update**:

My question is not about "migrating those questions" from Drupal.SE to DevOps.SE (also because of the valid reasons mentioned in Robert's answer). I mostly included the various tags/links as examples to get a better understand/feeling to better understand if such questions would be yes/no a good fit for DevOps.SE also.

PS: If you don't like Drupal, don't understand those questions at all, or would rather use another SE site (SF, SO, ...) to come up with a variation of the list in my question, please go ahead!

Answer (score 3):

As an administrative note, unless those questions are deemed off topic on those other sites, we have no cause to remove content from another site and the reputation/ownership that goes with it.

I just don't want to see users soliciting content from other sites because those questions can be asked here. That is not appropriate.

Besides, migrating content from elsewhere is not really a great way to build a new site. Migrated questions tend to be orphaned if the author does not have an account here, the tags don't typically match, the post doesn't often follow any posting guidelines you've established here, and anonymous content always has that odd, back-dated feel of long-forgotten questions that no one really cares about any longer.

Essentially, you would be loading this site up with a lot of questions asked and answered a long time ago… without imparting any of the benefits of reputation, ownership, or experience into the community that is supposed to take care of it.

That's why we don't do it.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Does my title/copy changes better describe your intent? 100% feel free to roll back those changes if I got it wrong.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Would it be acceptable/recommended, at least for those really interesting ones, to comment inviting the OPs to re-ask them on DevOps?

Comment: @DanCornilescu No, that would not be appropriate. With so many questions/subjects vying for attention, that would become (and has become) unworkable pretty quickly. We cannot allow folks to  solicit users and questions from other sites unless they are simply asking in the wrong place (i.e. off-topic)

Comment: @RobertCartaino I see. OK. Just curious. Thx.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: just to clarify: my question was specifically in the context of those posts being closed as off-topic on those sites, not the ones being accepted. I just now noticed your `unless those questions are deemed off topic on those other sites` note in your answer...